# XSL - How can I compare 2 sets of nodes?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following data

```
<parent>
    <child>APPLES</child>
    <child>APPLES</child>
    <child>APPLES</child>
</parent>
<parent>
    <child>APPLES</child>
    <child>BANANA</child>
    <child>APPLES</child>
</parent>
```

Is there a simple way to compare the parent nodes? Or will I have to nest a for-each within a for-each and test every child manually with position()?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: In my data there are 30+ <parent> nodes and I'm going through each one with <xsl:template match="parent">. I want to know when the child nodes of the current parent is different to the previous parent. E.G, it can be, X X X, then X X X, then Y X Y. I want to know when that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 has the function http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-xpath-functions-30-20130521/#func-deep-equal so you could write a template

```
<xsl:template match="parent[deep-equal(., preceding-sibling::parent[1])]">...</xsl:template>
```

to process those `parent` elements that are equal to their preceding sibling `parent`.

If you want to do it with XSLT 1.0 then for your simple case of a sequence of child elements with plain text content it should suffice to write a template

```
<xsl:template match="parent" mode="sig">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">|</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

and then to use it as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
  <xsl:variable name="this-sig">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="sig"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="pre-sig">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::parent[1]" mode="sig"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <!-- now compare e.g. -->
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$this-sig = $pre-sig">...</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>...</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

For more complex content you would need to refine the implementation of the template computing a "signature" string, you might want to search the web, I am sure Dimitre Novatchev has posted solutions on earlier, similar questions.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately I'm restricted to XSLT 1.0

Comment: In that case you'll have to implement an equivalent yourself, by means of a recursive template that takes two nodes to be compared as its arguments. The specification of XPath 2.0 deep-equal() might prove useful as a guide.

Comment: @DerekHo, I have added some suggestions on how to compare with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Genius! Didn't think about concatenating the parent into a flat string.